# AspectJ not capturing all methods

Tags: java, gwt, aspectj

I'm trying to log a Sting before every single method is run.

**Stack:** AspectJ, GWT, Java 7, Eclipse Luna's built in Jetty web server

**What doesn't work**
My advice is not capturing the overridden onModuleLoad() method in my EntryPoint class or any methods it calls.

**What does work**
It does capture methods executed after submitting the page to the server.

```
pointcut everything() : execution(* *.*(..));

before() : everything()
{
    System.out.println("Calling a method " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onModuleLoad` method is compiled by the GWT compiler into JavaScript - it is *not* run on the server at all, but in the client's browser. AspectJ cannot work on GWT code (since it cannot work on JavaScript), so this is not going to work.